# Phonegap Barcode Scanner Plugin and jQuery integration

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, barcode, barcode-scanner

(First of all, excuse if my english is not good...)
i follow the TMT barcode scanner tutorial and it works OK, but then i tried to incorporate some JQuery in the barcode example (following the "Use PhoneGap Media API & jQuery Mobile UI Framework" tutorial) ... Now the Barcode doesnt open anymore.

Here is the index.html:

```
<body>
<!--  a href="#" class="btn" onclick="scanCode();">Scan Code</a>-->
<div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="page-home">
<div data-role="header" data-nobackbtn="true" data-theme="e">
<h1>Barcode</h1>
</div> <!-- /header -->

<div data-role="content" id="content-manual" data-theme="a">
    <div data-role="button" id="playaudio" data-theme="e">Play</div>

</div>  <!-- /content-manual -->
</div>  <!-- /page -->
</body>
```

Here is the main.js:

```
$('#page-home').live('pageinit',function(){

$("#playaudio").live('tap', function() {
    // Note: two ways to access media file: web and local file        
    var scanCode = function() {
        window.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
            function(result) {
            alert("Scanned Code: " + result.text 
                    + ". Format: " + result.format
                    + ". Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
        }, function(error) {
            alert("Scan failed: " + error);
        });
    }
   });

   })
```

can you help me please?

Comment: have you tried `click` instead of `tap`

Comment: @dhaval Its not jQuery, its jQuery Mobile  

http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html